# how to read text file in java program

Tags: java

this is my java code. Please tell where i have to change the code so that i could be able to read the data from my text file i.e **test.txt**

```
import java.io.*;

class ShowFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // this is my file where my data is: test.TXT;
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin;

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            return;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage: ShowFile File "+ e);
            return;
        }

        // read characters until EOF is encountered
        do {
            i = fin.read();
            if (i != -1)
                System.out.print((char) i);
        } while(i != -1);

        fin.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the file in the Java Class Path ... Your passing the file as a argument(Not the file path.). So place the file in the Java class path (The path will be known to your jdk). Hope It will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line to read your file

```
       fin = new FileInputStream(yourfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the input stream here:

`fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);`

it's using the first argument to main (from the command line) `args[0]`  you can change that to your specific file.  Or just pass your file in.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
fin = new FileInputStream(path to your file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  This :

```
      String s=args[0];
      fin = new FileInputStream(s);
```

Compile java File:

```
      javac ShowFile.java
```

Pass The Command line  argument:

```
      java ShowFile file.txt
```